# curl query parameters get

Tags: curl, get

I get an error for this CURL command, whereas same works on Chrome DHC App. What am I missing here

```
[root@host125]# curl -sk -X 'GET' -H 'X-Auth-Token: [REDACTED]' -H 'Content-type: application/json' https://10.1.1.132/rest/rm-central/v1/recovery-sets?query="volumeType EQ 'vvol'"
{"badRequest": {"message": "QueryFilter Error :: Given Query Filter syntax 'query=' is not valid ", "code": 400}}
[root@host125]#
[root@host125]#
[root@host125]#
```

Answer (score 10):

Your URL seems wrong :

```
https://10.1.1.132/rest/rm-central/v1/recovery-sets?query="volumeType EQ 'vvol'"
```

especially the `query=` part.

The quotes should be like this :

```
'https://10.1.1.132/rest/rm-central/v1/recovery-sets?query=foobar'
```

or with "double quotes"

Answer (score 8):

Below CURL syntax solved my problem:

```
# curl -k -G -X 'GET' -H 'X-Auth-Token: 5127af39b7584d8c8897a0cad55accdc' -H 'Content-type: application/json' https://10.1.1.132/rest/rm-central/v1/recovery-sets -d "query=\"volumeType%20EQ%20'vvol'\""
```

Comment: -G/--get
    When used, this option will make all data specified with -d/--data or --data-binary to be used in a HTTP GET request instead of the POST request that otherwise would be used. The data will be appended to the URL with a '?' separator. https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl

Answer (score 5):

Use the `--data-urlencode` option of curl.

```
var=volumeType EQ 'vvol'
curl -sSLG "https://10.1.1.132/rest/rm-central/v1/recovery-sets" --data-urlencode "query=$var"
```

Note the [manpage](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode) indicates this is for POST requests:

> --data-urlencode
>
> (HTTP) This ***posts*** data, similar to the other -d, --data options with
> the exception that this performs URL-encoding.

[`-G`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-G) or [`--get`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-G) allows it to be used in a GET request:

> When used, this option will make all data specified with -d, --data,
> --data-binary or --data-urlencode to be used in an HTTP GET request instead of the POST request that otherwise would be used. The data
> will be appended to the URL with a '?' separator.